# SonarScanner CLI error: failed to request and parse localhost:9000

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube, .net-4.8, sonarcloud, sonarscanner

When using [SonarScanner](https://docs.sonarcloud.io/advanced-setup/ci-based-analysis/sonarscanner-for-net/) against a local source, following the suggested manual recipe for classic .NET and MSBuild, I find the following error (look at the bottom line):

```
SonarScanner for MSBuild 5.5.3
Using the .NET Framework version of the Scanner for MSBuild
Pre-processing started.
Preparing working directories...
11:30:19.134  Updating build integration targets...
11:30:23.344  Failed to request and parse 'http://localhost:9000/api/server/version': An error occurred while sending the request.
```

What's wrong? How to resolve this?

Answer (score -1):

It has worked for me: I am a beginner, so I didn't know - and the suggested manual recipe doesn't mention it - that local mode **requires** a running SonarQube instance, working on this particular endpoint.

So before you run SonarScanner locally, you need to have a local SonarQube server, at least with the default configuration of SonnarScanner.

How to install SonarQube locally? Here is the instruction: [Install the Server | SonarQube Docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/setup/install-server/).

Comment: that message is a bit misleading, i have error ```18:10:41.667  Failed to request and parse 'http://localhost:9000/api/server/version': Unable to connect to the remote server
18:10:41.668  Could not connect to the SonarQube server. Check that the URL is correct and that the server is available. URL: http://localhost:9000``` while running against remote server